# Buttons with classes

Tags: processing, control-p5

I'm using Processing 3 and the Controlp5 library.

Let's say I had a a method that was `apple.eat()`. How would I put that in a button?

`cp5.addButton("apple.eat")` doesn't work.

How would I make the button trigger `apple.eat()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way is to **add a CallbackListener to the button.**

```
Button eat = new Button(cp5, "eat apple");

eat.addCallback(new CallbackListener() {        
    @Override
    public void controlEvent(CallbackEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == 100) {
            apple.eat();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
cp5.addButton("appleEat");
```

And then define a function that calls the class:

```
void appleEat(int value){
  apple.eat();
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work as I create the buttons in a class and need to use multiple.

Comment: @ZacStewart Can you pass the function name in as a parameter? If you have other constraints, please post a [mcve] that demonstrates exactly what you're trying to do.